# SpringMVC Exception Handling: How to display the parameter being passed in the error page?

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat, exception

The number '12' that was passed doesn't exists. I want to display in an error.jsp page. "The Product called '12' doesn't exist. What method can I use to display that information?

SpringMVC Code

```
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public ModelAndView errorHandler(HttpServletRequest req, Exception exception) {
    logger.error("Request: " + req.getRequestURL() + " raised " + exception);

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.addObject("exception", exception);
    mav.addObject("url", req.getRequestURL());
    mav.setViewName("product/error");
    return mav;
  }
```

**Tomcat Console**

```
15:38:23.911 [http-bio-8080-exec-11] ERROR c.p.s.c.controller.ProductController - Request: http://localhost:8080/springchocolatestore/products/12 raised java.lang.RuntimeException
```

Comment: How was this argument passed?  Was it a parameter in a form?  If this input is mapped to a query string parameter or header, it will be accessible in the `HttpServletRequest` object.

Comment: Yeah It was mapped to a query String parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If the parameter you are trying to access is a query string parameter, you can easily access it from the `HttpServletRequest` object:

```
// Assuming that your parameter is named "num".
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public ModelAndView errorHandler(HttpServletRequest req, Exception exception) {
    logger.error("Request: " + req.getRequestURL() + " raised " + exception);
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    if (req.getParameterMap().containsKey("num")){
        mav.addObject("num", Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("num"));
    } 
    mav.addObject("exception", exception);
    mav.addObject("url", req.getRequestURL());
    mav.setViewName("product/error");
    return mav;
  }
```

All query string parameters are formatted as `String` objects, since they must be serialized into a URL, so you must convert the parameter back to its native type.  If you are just displaying this as a message, then this conversion is probably not necessary, however.